# call std::move with non-reference value?

Tags: c++, std, move

Looking at the signature of `std::move()`:

```
template< class T >
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t ) noexcept;
```

it accepts an rvalue reference, but can be called with a non-reference value, e.g. `std::string a = "a"; std::move(a)`. Why is this? What type will `T` have?

Comment: That isn't necessarily an rvalue reference.

Comment: `it accepts an rvalue reference` No, T&& is a universal reference, if T is a deduced template argument.

Comment: Also see https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers